# How to match a string that a specific word doesn't comes before it?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I trying to match the string **ARIBABA** only if **.get** doesn't comes before it.

Example:

> **ARIBABA** = config.get('SOMETHING', 'ARIBABA').lower()

I've tried this (down below) but it just doesn't match anything.

> ^(.get)\bARIBABA\b

Comment: exactly before it? or somewhere before in the string?

Comment: .get can't comes before ARIBABA

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must use PyPi regex library here:

```
import regex
s = "ARIBABA = config.get('SOMETHING', 'ARIBABA').lower()"
p = r"(?<!\.get\b.*)\bARIBABA\b"
print(regex.findall(p, s))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqtYwVZByTHI08nRyRHITM7PS8tM10tPLdFQD/b3dQ3x8PRzV9dRUIcqUdfUy8kvTy3S0FTiKgCqL1LSsLdRjAFpiEnS09KMSYIqjEkCKijKzCvRANujl5aZl5KYk6NRoKNQrKnJ9f8/AA).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    get                      'get'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ARIBABA                  'ARIBABA'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply try this one:

```
if 0 =< s.find('.get') < s.find('ARIBABA'):
```

`s.find(substring)` returns the lowest index of s that begins with the substring

Full example:

```
s = "config.get('SOMETHING', 'ARIBABA').lower()"
if 0 =< s.find('.get') < s.find('ARIBABA'):
    print('.get comes before ARIBABA')
```

Output:

```
.get comes before ARIBABA
```

EDIT:
if the substring doesn't exist in s, find will return -1, that's why I added the `0=<` condition

Comment: Very clever really!!! However it does not work for this case: `config.getNOISE('SOMETHING', 'ARIBABA').lower()` but I don't think this is a problem. +1

Comment: Thx for noticing, I edited my answer, now works for all the cases.

Answer (score -1):

Here is pure regex solution.

```
pattern = "^(?!.*\.get).*(ARIBABA)"
aribaba = "config.get('SOMETHING', 'ARIBABA').lower()"
try:
    re.search(pattern, aribaba).group(1)
except:
    print("No ARIBABA or get comes before")
```